# Search line by line in file for a string

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation

I need to search line by line to ensure a word appears on every line of a .text file. I am currently working on a batch script so it would be ideal if batch has the capabilities to do this. Otherwise, what are my options?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo Lines that have NOT the search word:
findstr /N /V /C:"theWord" theFile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use c++ over `.txt` file and then convert the file to batch file.